# Reading multiple raw files in Seurat

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have multiple single cell samples to analyze and I'm following the instructions in Satija Lab's website. I want to merge all the count files from all the samples at once, and associate the metadata to each sample.

For the `Read10x` command, is there a way to read multiple files at once, such as merging all the filter_featire_bc_matrix files?

I have all the samples saved in a directory on my desktop, is it possible to call the directory within the script for it to read all the raw counts?

This is what I have thus far:

```
# load the required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(Seurat) 
library(ggplot2)

-----------------------------------------------

# set up the working directory

wd = ("~/Seurat") setwd(wd)

# read all metadata

metadata = read.table("metadata_Jan2020.csv", sep=';', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
rownames(metadata) = metadata$LibraryID

#metadata
#mf = metadata

mf = metadata %>% filter(Type %in% c("PDAC", "NORMAL"))
mf = mf %>% filter(!(ID %in% c("PDAC-HTB2854")))`
```

Answer (score 2):

Seurat has [a vignette specifically for combining multiple 10x libraries](https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/merge_vignette.html).

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm wondering if there is a way to merge all counts before creating a Seurat object. I'd like to just create one Seurat object with all the counts.

Comment: You don't have to keep the intermediate Seurat objects.

Comment: To merge all counts before creating individual Seurat objects, you will need to give a prefix or a suffix to cell names. I would however advise to create individual Seurat objects with `apply()` or `mclapply()` and then `reduce()` these with Seurat's `merge()`, this will give you a single Seurat object with all your samples.

Comment: @haci How do I give a prefix or suffix?

Comment: Note that a month later, they put out a new vignette about merging data sets which is more complex:  https://satijalab.org/seurat/pancreas_integration_label_transfer.html

Comment: That vignette is over a year old. Also, it is for integration (batch correction), not simple merging of data sets.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Is there not a way to merge the counts from a directory and then create just one Seurat object?

Comment: See previous comment by @haci. However, there are many benefits of creating separate Seurat objects for each library, such as performing per-library QC.